# How to remove a value from a ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> and from a ListView row in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, arraylist, hashmap, simpleadapter

I have generated a `ListView` using a `SimpleAdapter`. I have a button named `remove` on each row of my ListView. I want to remove or delete the item that is set on that row as well as from the `items` ( which is of the type `Arraylist<Hashmap<String,String>>` when I click the `remove` button. I have done the following coding but it doesn't help. Can anyone guide me step by step what to do? My codes are as below:

```
     //here items is of the type  ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>


 ListAdapter k = new SimpleAdapter(cart_activity.this, items,
                                        R.layout.cart_list_view_items, new String[] {"Category","Details","quantity","images","Currency","Price","item_id"}, new int[] { R.id.cat_name_cart,
                                        R.id.cart_details,R.id.cart_qty,R.id.image_url,R.id.cart_currency,R.id.cart_price,R.id.cart_item_id}) {

            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                Log.i("arraylist position in cart activity and position",""+items.get(position).get("item_id")+"  "+position);
                Button remove=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.remove);

remove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        items.remove(position);
                    }
                });

    return v;
            }

        };

        salad_list.setAdapter(k);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

**1)** Remove [`.clear()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear%28%29) from `ArrayList` because it'll clear all details from `ArrayList`

**2)** Then add `notifyDataSetChanged()` that will refresh your **ListView**.

```
items.remove(position);
k.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: The row is getting deleted but the value is still present in my Arraylist<HashMap<String,String>> i.e I guess items.remove(position) doesn't remove that item from the Arraylist<Hashmap>

Comment: @Ann Are you using same `ArrayList` for both `OnCreate()` and `getView()` ?

Comment: Yes, I get the `ArrayList` from another `activity` in `oncreate()` and use the same arraylist in the `getview()`

Comment: @Ann It must be remove. How do you check that `ArrayList`  doesn't remove that item

Comment: I logged it, it got removed..sorry my mistake...and thanx its working now

Answer (score 0):

On click of remove button do:

```
items.remove(position);
k.notifyDataSetChanged();
```